# sublimetext pick a color scheme for a project

Tags: sublimetext3

I use sublimetext and as we are now switching our system to microservices I end up having to work at the same time on different projects at the same time (ex. main project and microservice project).

It would be really helpful to have some kind of visual clue about which editor I currently open (also for easier task switching).

I installed supersettings package, which should allow me to set custom sublimetext configuration per directory, but I'm struggling to configure different color_schemes or themes with it.

here's what I have in `Preferences.sublime-settings`:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Monokai"
}
```

when I open sublime I get this error:

```
Error loading colour scheme Monokai: Unable to open Monokai
```

any ideas?

## update

here's my sublime-project file:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "theme": "Adaptive",
    "settings": {
        // "color_scheme": "Packages/Material Monokai/MaterialMonokai.tmTheme",
    }
}
```

it doesn't seem to change the theme.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the full name of the color scheme file. It's just the file name, as Sublime will determine the path automatically. So, your settings should have this line:

```json
    "color_scheme": "MaterialMonokai.tmTheme"
```

As an aside, I would encourage you to make use of Sublime's [project features](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/projects.html) instead of relying on a very little-used plugin that may or may not work in all situations, and definitely doesn't have all the features that projects support.

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion, but I don't seem to be able to make it work. updated with my project file

Comment: @DonGiulio first, the line is commented out, was that intentional? Second, all you need is the name of the file - Sublime determines the path automatically. I've updated my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Well trying the project features I decided to try changing the theme, rather than the colour scheme, I prefer that. Anyhow none of these seem to work

Comment: @DonGiulio for the theme, you need the file's name as well - `"Adaptive.sublime-theme"`. As with color schemes, Sublime automatically discovers the file's location in your `Packages` directory.